# How can i save counter value on refresh?

Tags: javascript, php

js:

```
    var x = 0;

    function count() {
        x += 1;
        document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;

        $.cookie("key", value)
    }

</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="product">

  <div id="picture">
    <a href="?page=product" style="margin-left: 0px"> <img src="1h.jpg"
        alt="Online Shop" width="100%" height="100%">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="title"
    style="float: left; margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 5%; height: 40px; width: 70%; font-size: 22px;">
    <span> Oasis Beach Hotel </span> <span style="float: right"> Price:
        $50 </span>
  </div>

  <div id="title"
    style="float: left; margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 0%; height: 20px; width: 70%; font-size: 16px;">
    <span> Bookings: <input id="counting" type="text" />
    </span> <span style="float: right"> <?php echo' 
    <form action="  ';?> <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> <?php  echo'   " method="post" style="margin-left: 2%">


    <input type ="button" value = "ORDER" onclick = "count()"/><br><br>

    </form>
            ';?>

    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'trying to make booking system. The user must login and submit a offer. I'm trying to keep the number of booking on logout, but it keeps restarting when I refresh the page.

Comment: Have you check this documentation: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: [Cookies!](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Because you do not read the cookie value when the page loads.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63516541/104380

Answer (score 1):

So read the cookie value when the page loads

```
var value = parseInt($.cookie("key") || 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the value from cookie on refresh like this:

```
if($.cookie('key')){
  var x = parseInt($.cookie('key'));
}
else{
  var x = 0;
}
function count() {
  x += 1;
  document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;

  $.cookie("key", x); //I assume you want to save x and not val
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Store the values in cookies as mentioned by previous users.
You could also pass the value to PHP using AJAX and then store it in a session variable. You'll find the complete code for this on http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: Or MUCH better: [MDN Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) or [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)- w3schools is a poor reference site - please post examples when suggestion methods

Comment: It's good enough for beginners, and someone who has problems storing variables should visit it atleast once.

Comment: No, it is horrible for beginners since it teaches poor practices. I strongly recommend not to recommend it

Comment: Suggest something better then :D

Comment: I did, see my very first comment

Comment: Jquery ajax is the official documentation, which is a very good source, if you have some background with jquery. About MDN ajax, I never tried that, so there you go